# How get jobs paramethers in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have three jobs: `A`, `B`, `C`.
Job `A` generate paramether `FIRST_PAM`, job `B` generate paramether `SECOND_PAM`.
I want pass `FIRST_PAM` & `SECOND_PAM` to `C` job. How I can do it? Can I get not enviroment variables in pipeline script?

My pipeline:

```
stage 'A'
build job: 'A'
//def FIRST_PAM= // get FIRST_PAM from A. HOW?
stage 'B'
build job: 'B'
//def SECOND_PAM= // get SECOND_PAM from B. HOW?
stage 'C'
build job: 'C', parameters: [string(name: 'FIRST_PAM', value: FIRST_PAM), string(name: 'SECOND_PAM', value: SECOND_PAM) ]
```